# Conceptual Question Regarding the Yolo Object Detection Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

My understanding is that the motivation for Anchor Boxes (in the Yolo v2 algorithm) is that in the first version of Yolo (Yolo v1) it is not possible to detect multiple objects in the same grid box. I don't understand why this is the case.

Also, the original paper by the authors (Yolo v1) has the following quote:

"Each grid cell predicts B bounding boxes and confidence scores for those boxes. These confidence scores reflect how confident the model is that the box contains an object and also how accurate it thinks the box is that it predicts."

Doesn't this indicate that a grid cell can recognize more than one object? In their paper, they take B as 2. Why not take B as some arbitrarily higher number, say 10?

Second question: how are the Anchor Box dimensions tied to the Bounding Box dimensions, for detecting a particular object? Some websites say that the Anchor Box defines a shape only, and others say that it defines a shape and a size. In either case, how is the Anchor Box tied to the Bounding Box?

Answer (score 2):

You're right that YOLOv1 has multiple (B) bounding boxes, but these are not assigned to ground truths in an effective or systematic way, and therefore also don't infer bounding boxes accurate enough.

As you can read on blog posts over the internet, an Anchor/Default Box is a box in the original image which corresponds to a specific cell in a specific feature map, which is assigned with specific aspect ratio and scale.
The scale is usually dictated by the feature map (deeper feature map -> large anchor scale), and the aspect ratio vary, e.g. {1:1, 1:2, 2:1} or {1:1, 1:2, 2:1, 1:3, 3:1}.
By the scale and aspect ratio, a specific shape is dictated, and this shape, with a position dictated by the position of the current cell in the feature map, is compared to ground truth bounding boxes in the original image.

Different papers have different assignment schemes, but it's usually goes like this: (1) if the IoU of the anchor on the original image with a GT is over some threshold (e.g. 0.5), then this is a positive assignment to the anchor, (2) if it's under some threshold (e.g. 0.1), then it's a negative assignment, and (3) if there's a gap between these two thresholds - then the anchors in between are ignored (in the loss computation).

This way, an anchor is in fact like a "detector head" responsible for specific cases, which are the most similar to it shape-wise. It is therefore responsible to detect objects with shape similar to it, and it infers both confidence to each class, and bounding box parameters **relative to it**, i.e. how much to modify the anchor's height, width, and center (in the two axes) to receive the correct bounding box.

Because of this assignment scheme, which distributes the responsibility effectively between the different anchors, the bounding box prediction is more accurate.

Another downside to YOLOv1's scheme is the fact that it decouples bounding box and classification. On one hand, this saves computation, but on the other hand - the classification is on the level of grid cell. Therefore the B options for bounding boxes all have the same class prediction. This means, for example, that if there are multiple objects of **different** class with the same center (e.g. person holding a cat), then the classification of at least all but one will be wrong. Note that it is theoretically possible that other predictions of adjacent grid cells will compensate on this wrong classification, but it is not promised, in particular since by the YOLOv1's scheme, the center is the assignment criteria.